# Convert PHP response Object to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, dom

I tried to call javascript to PHP service. Then Am getting a response from that service. 
But, Now I need convert that response Object to JSON Object.

My PHP Service like,

```
if ( isset($_POST['S3']) && ($_POST['S3'] == 'true' || $_POST['S3'] == 'TRUE')){
$result = $client->detectLabels([
    'Image' => [ 
        'S3Object' => [
            'Bucket' => 'spiralup',
            'Name' => ''.$filename
        ],
    ],
    'MaxLabels' => 10,
    'MinConfidence' => 60
]);
}else {
    $result = $client->detectLabels([
        'Image' => [ 
            'Bytes' => $contents
        ],
        'MaxLabels' => 10,
        'MinConfidence' => 60
    ]);
}
//echo($result);

//echo $result->getPath('Labels/Name');
//> ACTIVE

// Convert the Model to a plain array
var_export($result->toArray()['Labels']);
```

My Javascript code like,

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("imagePath", "D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\webcam\\webcamImage\\20181009091628.jpg");
form.append("S3", "false");

var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:90/AWS_Test.php?Content-Type=application/json",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {},
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Here, My Sample response Object.

```
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'Name' => 'Sathish',
          'Id' => 91,
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'Name' => 'Anish',
          'Id' => 92,
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
          'Name' => 'Anil',
          'Id' => 99,
        ),
        3 => 
        array (
          'Name' => 'Chennai',
          'Id' => 69,
        ),
        4 => 
        array (
          'Name' => 'Beard',
          'Id' => 64,
        ),
      )
```

But I need following like this,

```
[   {
        "0":[{"Name" : "Sathish", "Id" : 91}], 
        "1":[{"Name" : "Anish", "Id" : 92}], 
        "2":[{"Name" : "Anil", "Id" : 99}], 
        "3":[{"Name" : "Chennai", "Id" : 69}], 
        "4":[{"Name" : "Beard", "Id" : 64}]
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance and If you vote down please let me know why.

Comment: Could you also provide the relevant code for the function which returns this data? :)

Comment: you should have to use like `var obj= '<?php echo json_encode($phpArr); ?>';` then after `obj=JSON.parse(obj)`

Comment: The expected output is not a valid json, are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: The expected output you've shown is not actually valid JSON. Maybe you just showed the array indexes for illustration, I don't know. But anyway to convert a PHP object or array to (valid) JSON you just need to use the [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function. A simple google search would tell you that. (P.S. if you want to know the possible reasons why people vote you down, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: thanks @ manikant Gautam. I already tried, it throwing some error

Comment: Well then show us what you tried, and quote the error message!

Comment: `it throwing some error` what it is ?

Comment: we can't guess what code you wrote, what your error is or where it occurs. We can't read your disk, your screen...or your mind. Please help us to help you by providing accurate, detailed, and specific information about your problem. You can't expect a mechanic to fix your car just by saying "it's broken", or a doctor to diagnose your illness just by telling him "I don't feel well", especially if they can't even see the car or the person. It's the same with code. I don't understand why you would think that saying "throwing some error" would actually enable anyone to assist you?

Comment: @manikantgautam BTW in the situation you showed, if you just do `var obj= <?php echo json_encode($phpArr); ?>;` without the single quotes then it will inject the data as if it was a hard-coded literal object declaration in the JavaScript. Then there's no need for JSON.parse()

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Swap var_export with json_encode and that should do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap `var_export` with `json_encode` and that should do the job:

```
json_encode($result->toArray()['Labels']);
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

**Why not use this model?**

```
$arr=array(
    array(
        'name'=>'test1',
        'id'=>'1',
    ),
    array(
        'name'=>'test2',
        'id'=>'2',
    ),
    array(
        'name'=>'test3',
        'id'=>'3',
    ),

);
echo json_encode($arr); ///[{"name":"test1","id":"1"},{"name":"test2","id":"2"},{"name":"test3","id":"3"}]
```